# Directive calls setValidity(false) on field but field validity never changes according to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

With reference to this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/GzC9ufa1WJmKQ6Ad15v9?p=preview

I have a directive that runs a test and then calls `$scope.form['myfield'].setValidity()` with the result. However this does not reflect in the view or the controller.

Simple example that will always set `false`:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.on('blur change', function() {
        console.log("start valid:" + scope.form[attrs.name].$valid);
        scope.form[attrs.name].$setValidity('myfield', false);
        console.log("end valid:" + scope.form[attrs.name].$valid);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

in my view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" name="myfield" my-directive/>
```

Console logging confirms that when the event in the directive first fires, the field is valid, then after setValidity it becomes false. On subsequent events it is false before the event fires. However, when I print out `{{form['myfield'].$valid}}` in the view, it remains `true` regardless.

I guess this is might be a timing thing, that by the time `setValidity(false)` runs in the directive, the view has already checked. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in an $apply to trigger a digest:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.on('blur change', function() {
        console.log("start valid:" + scope.form[attrs.name].$valid);
        scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.form[attrs.name].$setValidity('myfield', false);
            console.log("end valid:" + scope.form[attrs.name].$valid);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Cool, hadn't heard of $digest/$apply before now but this article explained handily: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html

Comment: Yes, any code that angular doesn't know about (like jquery blur/change events), $apply is need to manually trigger the digest cycle.